# Mvn dependency resolution for local repo

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to add a local respository to my project which is managed by maven.
I did the following steps to add the local repo to maven

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.example.somename -DartifactId=somefile.jar -Dversion=1.0 -Dfile=C:\Users\username\mvn_respos\somefile.jar
```

Then I added the dependecy on my pom.xml

Now I get the following error.

```
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\com\example\sonename\somefile\1.0\somefile-1.0.jar'
```

However when I navigate to the particular directory, the file does exist.
What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: `sonfile.jar` is that a typo in the question, or is that the actual command you ran?

Comment: It was a typo, which I've corrected.

Comment: Have you tried running the install-file goal with the `-Dpackaging=jar` option?

Comment: Yup done that too. Same result.

Comment: When do you get the error? `mvn dependency:resolve`?

Comment: I think Eclipse runs the dependency resolve as soon as the pom.xml is updated and saved. That's when I'm getting it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sonfile.jar -DgroupId=com.example.somename -DartifactId=sonfile -Dversion=0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

execute the command in the same directory where is the jar, so you cannot write all the path in Dfile

Comment: This doesn't work says,`Artifact information is missing or incomplete, groupId missing`.